# Removing double quotes from the beging and end of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array stored in a file, when I read this file to variable in Ruby it returns double quotes at the beginning and end of the array. I use Ruby 2.7.0

```
irb
irb(main):065:0> ports = IO.read('/ports_values')
irb(main):066:0> ports
=> "['127.0.0.1:6601:6601', '127.0.0.1:8000:8000', '127.0.0.1:7200:7200', '127.0.0.1:9201:9201', '5606:5606', '6304:6504', '6305:6505']"
```

But what I need this:

```
irb(main):066:0> ports
    => ['127.0.0.1:6601:6601', '127.0.0.1:8000:8000', '127.0.0.1:7200:7200', '127.0.0.1:9201:9201', '5606:5606', '6304:6504', '6305:6505']
```

without double quotes and I tried this ,but it did not work

```
irb(main):067:0> ports.gsub /"/, ' '
=> "['127.0.0.1:6601:6601', '127.0.0.1:8000:8000', '127.0.0.1:7200:7200', '127.0.0.1:9201:9201', '5606:5606', '6304:6504', '6305:6505']"
```

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that hasn't been maintained in years and has unpatched security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Because, I use exactly  "ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-linux]". I use chef Zero (chefworkstation:21.5.462) kitchen tool (Kitchen converge) for test before deployment.

Comment: You don’t have an array with double quotes at its beginning and end. What you have is a _string_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = "['127.0.0.1:6601:6601', '127.0.0.1:8000:8000', '127.0.0.1:7200:7200', '127.0.0.1:9201:9201', '5606:5606', '6304:6504', '6305:6505']"
a.slice(1..-2).split(",").map{ |b| b.strip.gsub("'","")}
```

o/p: `["127.0.0.1:6601:6601", "127.0.0.1:8000:8000", "127.0.0.1:7200:7200", "127.0.0.1:9201:9201", "5606:5606", "6304:6504", "6305:6505"]`